# Is it redundant to add a 'structure identifier' at the end of a struct. What use does it serve?

Tags: c

When I mean identifier I mean a name appended after the semi-column of the struct- as seen below:

```
  item struct [<tag_identifier>] {

        <type_specifier> <identifier>;
        <type_specifier> <identifier>;

        } [<identifier>[, <identifier>
```

Take a look at this struct and notice 'List' appended at the bottom.

```
typedef struct list{
  int value;
  struct list *next;
} List;
```

vs

```
typedef struct list{
  int value;
  struct list *next;
};
```

What is the purpose of adding a variable called List?

Comment: the answer given by `ouah` is very much to the point. Your comment can be answered with a simple question .. If you write `typedef int mytype` *it doesn't allocate memory does it?*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct list{
    int value;
    struct list *next;
 } List;
```

declares `struct list` type and declares `List` as a type alias for type `struct list` .

```
typedef struct list{
   int value;
   struct list *next;
};
```

declares `struct list` type but does not declare any type alias. It is valid but the use of `typedef` is pointless.

Comment: So it declares memory allocation for the struct in 'List'? Is that all?

Comment: It's not allocating any memory.  It's just aliasing the name.

Comment: @BDillan neither the first or the second reserve any storage or defines any object.

Comment: No -- it's a `typedef` declaration: `typedef type alias_to_type` where `type` happens to be `struct struct_name {/*the whole definition*/}`

Answer (score 0):

It combines two declarations:

```
typedef struct list {
    int value;
    struct list *next;
} List;
```

is the same as

```
struct list {
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list List;
```

First one declares a new structure type, second one creates an alias.